# Can't understand the conditional execution flow

Tags: javascript

A simple js snippet. Why does it always alert

'result is empty'

As per my understanding, `if` block should get executed since `result!=""` is `true` and alert

'result is not empty'.

```
<script>
var result = false;
if(result != "")
alert('result is not empty')
else
alert('result is empty')
</script>
```

Comment: Because "" is a falsy value.

Comment: @jalooc No, that's not the reason

Comment: @Bergi of course it is: `!=` casts values so that `false != ''` resolves to `false`.

Comment: @jalooc But it casts `""` to a number (`Number("")`), not to a boolean (`Boolean("")`), so its falsiness doesn't matter.

Comment: @Bergi the "0" number is still falsy, isn't it? Just execute `false != ''` in the devtools console. You'll get `false`, not `true` as you falsely state in your question.

Comment: @jalooc The number `0` is not coerced a boolean anywhere, so its falsiness doesn't matter either? You can also try `"0" == false`, where `"0"` is definitely not a falsy value.

Comment: @Bergi As I said, I meant the zero number, not the string. Zero as a string is truthy, whilst zero as a number is falsy. But that doesn't matter anyway, I was just referring to what you wrote about casting to a number. What matters though, is that `false != ''` evaluates to `false`, which is where you are wrong and why it alerts what it alerts.

Comment: @jalooc I never claimed that `false != ''` wouldn't evaluate to `false`, all I am saying is that it has nothing to do with `''` being a falsy (i.e. `Boolean(…) === false`) value.

Comment: "since `result!=""` is `true`" - isn't that what you wrote in the question?

Answer (score 3):

It's because `!=` does implicit type conversion. If you used the strict version, `!==`, it would do what you expect. But the loose version, `!=`, will convert both of those operands to numbers, and both `""` and `false` convert to `0`, so `"" != false` is false, because it ends up (through a series of convolutions) being `0 != 0`.

This is laid out in detail in [Abstract Equality Comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) algorithm in the specification:

1. ReturnIfAbrupt(x).
2. ReturnIfAbrupt(y).
3. If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then
   Return the result of performing Strict Equality Comparison x === y.
4. If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
5. If x is undefined and y is null, return true.
6. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String,
   return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
7. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number,
   return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
8. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
9. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
10. If Type(x) is either String, Number, or Symbol and Type(y) is Object, then
    return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).
11. If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String, Number, or Symbol, then
    return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.
12. Return false.

As we can see from the above, if we start out with `false` and `""`, then:

- We follow Step 8, convert `false` to `0`, and start again with `0 != ""`
- We follow Step 6, convert `""` to `0`, and start again with `0 != 0`
- We follow Step 3 and get the result `false` (because we're doing `!=`, whereas the algorithm is defined in terms of `==`).

Comment: Thank you @Crowder for your detailed answer. Keep it up. Thanks for the link as well.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript two falsy things can be equal, as in this case, where `result != ""` yields `false`.

You need to use an strict comparison, i.e. `!==` to make the comparison. `result !== ""` yields `true`.

Comment: It's the other way round? `false != ""` yields `false`.

Comment: @Risadinha Thank you, the reasoning was correct, but I swapped the true and false!! I've corrected it

Answer (score 0):

Javascript checks for truthy values.

```
false != ""
```

is false

```
false !== ""
```

is true so you can try it.